# Function always returns the same value

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm working on an Windows 8 app and using JavaScript for the first time. I haven't had any big issues until now.
The following function makes a request and gets a JSON object. Comparing the result I get from my browser and from the debugger everything is okay in the first request.
After that it seems like the server is always returning the same value, which is not the case

```
(function () {
    "use strict";


    function getPrice(currency) {
    var url;

    switch(currency) {
        case "usd":
            url = urlUSD;
            break;

        case "eur":
            url = urlEUR;
            break;

        case "gbp":
            url = urlGBP;
            break;
    }

    WinJS.xhr({ url: url }).then(
        function (response) {
            var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            switch(currency) {
                case "usd":
                    console.log(json.data);
                    sharedData.usd = parseFloat(json.data);
                    console.log(sharedData.usd);
                    break;
                case "eur":
                    console.log(json.data);
                    sharedData.eur = parseFloat(json.data);
                    console.log(sharedData.eur);
                    break;
                case "gbp":
                    console.log(json.data);
                    sharedData.gbp = parseFloat(json.data);
                    console.log(sharedData.gbp);
                    break;
            }
        },
        function (error) { console.log(error); },
        function (progress) { }
    );
}
```

The calling function

```
(function () {
"use strict";

function onTimer() {
    Exchanges.getPrices("usd");
    setTimeout(onTimer, 1000*60);
}

setTimeout(onTimer, 1000);
})();
```

Comment: how did you confirm that the server is not returning the same data?

Comment: That switch statement in the success function is pretty useless. You can just use `sharedData[currency]` instead of `sharedData.usd`, `sharedData.eur` etc.

Comment: @David McMullin
i can get the same data from my browser.
And i can confirm the data being return by the server is mostly different every time i query it. As for my code, it always returns the same (first) value

Comment: @rjmunro
thanks for the tip :)

Comment: ok, have you tried confirming which URL your code is requesting? If you use firebug or chrome-dev-tools you can just take a look in the the Network panel to see which URL was requested, and what the response contained.

Comment: one last thing, since you used the word `return`, I assume whatever function calls `getPrice` does something with `sharedData`, as the `getPrice` function does not actually return anything. However, `sharedData` is updated asynchronously, so I'm curious to know what the calling function looks like.

Comment: @DavidMcMullin is right. This function should return the promise, and the caller needs to `.then` the promise to wait for the result. Otherwise, it just runs ahead with the value left over from last time.

Comment: @DavidMcMullin you assume correctly, the idea is to get sharedData updated asynchronously. Then i have a chart that fetchs the sharedData every x seconds.
As for the calling function, i use a background task. I updated my original post with the calling function

Answer (score 0):

There are many techniques to handle cache issue. I have used the technique of adding an timestamp parameter to the url to fix this in past.

```
var timestamp = Date.now();
url += '?' + 'timestamp=' + timestamp;
```

Comment: does the webservice fail if you add an extra parameter? i have used this with azure blob storage sas url also.

Comment: it fails when i add anything to the URL but i've been trying from your tip, to insert random data to the request header, but the problem persists

this is the url btw `https://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCEUR/money/ticker`

Comment: try  Cache-Control: no-cache header

Comment: I saw that api returns 'now' field in json payload and in my test the value was different for each call. if that is the case, the other values are not changing and request is indeed going to the server. need to follow up more on the api documentation.